# Statements dealing with variables independent of bound variables in a quantifier

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working on a proof now, but it hinges on whether or not the following equivalence holds:

$$\forall i\epsilon I (P(x)) = P(x)$$

Where i and x are independent of each other, x is not necessarily a value in I, and P is a statement about x. Now despite my intuition, I am not comfortable just trying to assume this. I've tried different search terms in Google and have not been able to come up with anything that proves this or states it as an axiom for elementary/naive set theory. Is this something I should just take as an axiom or is there a way to prove this?

UPDATE: As requested, the full thing I'm trying to prove is

$$\forall i \epsilon I (y\epsilon B) = y\epsilon B $$

Essentially that the statement "for all i that are the element of the set I, y is an element of B" and "y is an element of B" are equivalent where y and i are independent of each other and B is an arbitrary set.

Comment: What is the "exact reading" of the formula ? If $i$ is not present into $P(x)$, $\forall i \ P(x)$ has the same "meaning" of $P(x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA : I added the exact reading of what I am wanting to prove instead of the generalized question. Although of course I am interested in the answer to the former, I do wonder if the latter generalized case that I originally posed can be taken as an overall rule for any arbitrary statement P.

Comment: Yes, it works. Due to the fact that $i$ does not occur nowhere in the formula $y \in B$, the last one holds or not irrespective of $i$.

Comment: Ok. Just making sure I can take this as an assumption in my larger proof. Thank you kindly @MauroALLEGRANZA .